# VBA to transfer inner text from html page to excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

**This image shows what I use the following macro**
[image]

But this code stops after the opening of two or three URLs and we see the following error message,
1.  run-time err  91
2.  object variable or with block not set

```
Sub test()

Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim sURL As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim HtmlToText As String
Dim result
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow  'Start the loop on the second row of column A. Until the last URL..

    Set wb = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
    sURL = Cells(i, 1)
    wb.navigate sURL
    wb.Visible = False
    While wb.Busy
      DoEvents
    Wend
    'HTML document
    Set doc = wb.document
    Dim Name As Variant
    Dim Posts As Variant
    Dim Followers As Variant
    Dim Following As Variant
    Dim DivValue As Variant
    Dim DivValueSplit As Variant
    Dim DivValueResult As Variant
    Dim Biography As Variant

    Name = doc.getElementsByClassName("AC5d8 notranslate")(0).innerText
    Posts = doc.getElementsByClassName("g47SY")(0).innerText
    Followers = doc.getElementsByClassName("g47SY")(1).innerText
    Following = doc.getElementsByClassName("g47SY")(2).innerText
    'dd = web.document.querySelector("div.-vDIg span").innerText
    DivValue = doc.getElementsByClassName("-vDIg")(0).innerText

    'DivValueSplit = Split(DivValue, "<br>")
    'If UBound(DivValueSplit) = 2 Then
    '   DivValueResult = DivValueSplit(1) & DivValueSplit(2)
     '  j = InStr(DivValueResult, "</span>")
      ' Biography = Mid(DivValueResult, 7, j - 7)
    'ElseIf sURL = "https://www.instagram.com/philipplein/" Then
     ' DivValueResult = DivValueSplit(0)
      'j = InStr(DivValueResult, "</h1>")
      'Biography = Mid(DivValueResult, 19, j - 5)
    'Else
     '   DivValueResult = DivValueSplit(1)
      '  j = InStr(DivValueResult, "</span>")
       ' Biography = Mid(DivValueResult, 7, j - 7)
    'End If

    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = Name
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3) = Followers
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 4) = Following
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 5) = Posts
    Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 6) = DivValue
    'Biography = Replace(re1, "<span>", "")

    'Cells(i, 2) = HtmlToText
    ' myarray = Split(Data, vbCrLf)
err_clear:



      If Err <> 0 Then
          Err.Clear
          Resume Next
        End If
        wb.Quit
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.  Consult the tags for the correct usage.

Comment: DO NOT use `DoEvents` in order to make your program responsive while waiting for something or while doing something. It could cause issues and unexpected bug

Comment: You are creating and destroying the internet explorer object each time you loop. Don't. Create once and use navigate to go to next URL i.e. create internet explorer object before loop and .Quit after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:**

Two methods. One with no browser opening, issuing [XMLHTTP request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/), the other using Internet Explorer.

If there is an API way to get this done I would definitely go with that. The following 2 methods ***currently*** work for all your shown URLs.

**Note:**

These are based on end part of URL in sheet i.e. the person's name. See image at bottom.

### XMLHTTP request:

This uses a custom class `clsHTTP` to hold the `XMLHTTP object`. It has 2 methods. One, `GetString`, to issue the request and parse out a section of the response. The other, `GetInfo`, to take the string returned by `GetString` and parse out the elements of interest and return them in an array.

**TODO:**

The class can be developed. It is bare bones. In particular, it could do with error handling added in, for example, to handle loss of server connection.

**VBA:**

Class `clsHTTP`:

```
Option Explicit

Private http As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
End Sub

Public Function GetString(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        GetString = Split(Split(sResponse, "ProfilePage"":")(1), "comments_disabled")(0)   
    End With
End Function

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal sResponse As String) As Variant
    Dim results(0 To 4)
    'Name, Followers,  Following,Posts,Biography
    On Error Resume Next
    results(0) = Split(sResponse, """full_name"":""")(1)
    results(1) = Split(Split(sResponse, """count"":")(1), "}")(0)
    results(2) = Split(Split(sResponse, """count"":")(2), "}")(0)
    results(3) = Split(Split(sResponse, """count"":")(4), ",")(0)
    results(4) = Split(Split(sResponse, """biography"":""")(1), """,")(0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetInfo = results
End Function
```

Standard module `module 1`:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim http As clsHTTP, sResponse As String, lastRow As Long, groupResults()
    Set http = New clsHTTP
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.instagram.com/"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRow
        Case 1
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A2").Value
        Case Else
            arr = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
        End Select

        ReDim groupResults(0 To lastRow - 2)
        Dim results(0 To 4), counter As Long, i As Long
        With http
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If Len(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1)) > Len(BASE_URL) Then
                     sResponse = .GetString(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1))
                    groupResults(counter) = .GetInfo(sResponse)
                    sResponse = vbNullString
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With

        For i = LBound(groupResults) To UBound(groupResults)
            .Cells(2 + i, "B").Resize(1, UBound(results) + 1) = groupResults(i)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### **Internet Explorer:**

I will write something better a little later but the following places the loop inside of where you have create the Internet Explorer object so you don't keep creating and destroying. It introduces waits for elements to be present and also for page loading.

---

**TODO:**

Some initial changes I would make:

1. Refactor the code to have separate functions/subs that handle the data extraction;
2. Add in methods to manage failed connections/timeouts.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, lastRow As Long, arr(), groupResults()

    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://www.instagram.com/"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lastRow
        Case 1
            Exit Sub
        Case 2
            ReDim arr(1, 1): arr(1, 1) = .Range("A2").Value
        Case Else
            arr = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Value
        End Select

        ReDim groupResults(0 To lastRow - 2)
        Dim results(0 To 4), counter As Long, i As Long
        With IE
            .Visible = True

            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                If Len(BASE_URL & arr(i, 1)) > Len(BASE_URL) Then
                    .navigate BASE_URL & arr(i, 1)

                    While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                    'Name, Followers,  Following,Posts,Biography
                    Dim aNodeList As Object, ele As Object, t As Date
                    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5

                    t = Timer

                    Do
                        DoEvents
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set ele = .document.querySelector(".rhpdm")
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                    Loop While ele Is Nothing

                    '   Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
                    results(0) = ele.innerText
                    Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".g47SY")
                    results(1) = aNodeList.item(0).innerText
                    results(2) = aNodeList.item(1).innerText
                    results(3) = aNodeList.item(2).innerText
                    results(4) = .document.querySelector(".rhpdm ~ span").innerText
                    Set aNodeList = Nothing : Set ele = Nothing
                    groupResults(counter) = results
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If 
            Next        
            .Quit '<== Remember to quit application
        End With

        For i = LBound(groupResults) To UBound(groupResults)
            .Cells(2 + i, "B").Resize(1, UBound(results) + 1) = groupResults(i)
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Results:**

[image]