# Import Data using JSON

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have developed a code to scrape data from a websites but since I know very little about JSON I could be able to get the output as I want, the code was developed for  this web: https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/1 now I am replicating my code for other websites having json like this web :https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=hvac&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA ; but this code is not functioning properly. Here is my code(I want it to be generic for most webs)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As XMLHTTP60, Html As HTMLDocument, col As Variant, csrf As Variant, i&, page As Long
    Dim headers(), ws As Worksheet, iCol As Collection

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("SrNo", "Name", "Address", "Mobile", "Email")
    Set Http = New XMLHTTP60
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

    For page = 1 To 8 'To cover all pages

        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=hvac&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA" & CStr(page), Falsev 'Last letter of URL is page number whose range will be given in outerloop
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        Set iCol = New Collection
        With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
            For i = 0 To .Length - 1
                iCol.Add Split(Split(.Item(i).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
            Next i
        End With

        Dim r As Long, results()
        ReDim results(1 To iCol.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
        r = 0
        For Each col In iCol
            r = r + 1
            With Http
                .Open "GET", "https://www.yelp.com/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
                .send
                csrf = .responseText
            End With

            csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

            Dim json As Object
            With Http
                .Open "POST", "https://www.yelp.com/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
                .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
                Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

                Dim orgName As String, address As String, srNo As Long, city As String
                Dim state As String, tel As String, mobile As String, website As String, email As String

                On Error Resume Next
                orgName = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_orgName")
                address = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_add")

                srNo = r                         '<unsure where this is coming from.

                mobile = json("infor")("0")("Mobile")

                email = json("infor")("0")("Email")
                On Error GoTo 0

                Dim arr()
                arr = Array(srNo, orgName, address, tel, email)
                For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
                    results(r, i + 1) = arr(i)
                Next
            End With
        Next col
        Set iCol = Nothing: Set json = Nothing
        ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Please also let me know mistakes I am doing, so that i will take care of those in future.

Comment: Oh! so I have to design again & again for each website..

Comment: Pretty much I'm afraid. That is part and parcel of web-scraping. The re-usable stuff is the techniques you deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

No.

I would go so far as to say it is impossible you can write something generic ***for most webs*** . One could say the generic part is the parser itself. But you need to have some familiarity with the json structure of each endpoint to appropriately direct parsing. Json itself has defined structural syntax/components, but what you want from those will have different access paths and require different handling to do so. Then there are the arguments that may need to be supplied and differences in output format.

**What is the best scenario?**

If you have a set list of urls (ideally API endpoints) you have a better chance of writing something that might last for a while as you can familiarise yourself with the json returned. But how generic is this? It's really just branched code.

**Re-usable stuff:**

Might be the non parser stuff which can be generalised e.g. methods and classes you create that parse out the paths for the entire structure and look for key words and return you those paths? Helper functions you write that might recursively write out nested structures etc. Code that makes the request and handles fails etc.... I would definitely recommend looking into classes for re-usable code in web-scraping.

Class based examples:

I will add to this as and when

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301153/6241235
2. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69009/vba-clickbot-featuring-ajax-waiting-and-element-searching

Comment: Ok I got it, can you please sort out this code.. for this web: https://www.yelp.com/search?cflt=hvac&find_loc=San+Francisco%2C+CA  your comments are so helpful.

Comment: Sure but should be asked as a new question making it clear you are focused on that one endpoint. This current question is useful however as it is a recurring theme on SO.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684570/web-scrapping-using-json?noredirect=1#comment99935114_56684570